# how to capture sequence of performed steps in web application and re do the same for testing?

Tags: c#, testing, web

I am new developer. every day at least i do same launching our application and giving credential and select same drop down values every time?

how to capture the sequence of step and re do with capturing steps?

C# code or any tool suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: you described ui testing framework. Maybe try with Selenium? http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply automate a couple actions for yourself, [tiny task](https://www.vtaskstudio.com/tinytask.php) is just enough task automation. Just save the output as an exe, and you can run it to repeat the steps beyond a single session, or take advantage of the hotkeys. When tiny task isn't enough, look into autohotkey, selenium, and other task or testing automation frameworks.

Comment: That is an interesting piece of software. I don't fully understand how it differs from a standard console application except that it can record? Anywho, it looks neat!

Comment: Thank you JMC. i will take a look on tiny task for others we dont have budget. also i would like to know more about the fetching all get/post calls and re do the same using C#.

Comment: for the fetching and repeating network activity, there is the high-level POSTMAN (and its like) and the much lower level Wireshark (for packets and stuff).